# Someone generous with their thoughts

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that means the characteristic of being generous with one's thoughts.  For instance, a mentor would have this characteristic--that would be a person who had agreed to provide a leg-up for a junior person in their profession by sharing information and feedback. I am looking for a positive word because, of course, someone who is "generous with their thoughts" might be a busybody.

The particular context is that I am trying to describe a new working group that will need to come up with innovative ways to solve problems and one of the rules of the group will be that everyone be equally generous with their thoughts, as opposed to being entirely dead wood or, even worse, only speaking up to shoot down other people's ideas.  So I want to convey that offering your ideas is a gift and that those who do not want to offer ideas do not have this admirable characteristic (and should not volunteer for the group).

Actually, the folks who participate here could be said to have this characteristic!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for people who are ***forthcoming***.

Lexico:

> ***[forthcoming](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/forthcoming)***
> *ADJECTIVE*
> **2.1**(of a person) willing to divulge information.
> ‘their daughter had never been forthcoming about her time in Europe’

Macmillan:

> ***[forthcoming](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/forthcoming#forthcoming_9)***  ​‌‌ ​*ADJECTIVE*
> **3**  helpful and willing to tell you things
>
> James was more forthcoming than I expected.